# What is the best approach to checking stock in a Woocommerce meta query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a one-way relationship between two products, with the 'linked-to' product outputting the product information of the 'linked-from' product.

I'm able to use a custom field to create the relationship, and use a meta query to generate the results based on this field, but I also need to check that the 'linked-from' product is still either In Stock (if not being stock managed), or has more than 0 as a stock quantity.

This is the approach I have taken so far, which returns no matching results (when indeed there are matches):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'meta_key'      => 'exact_new_version',
    'meta_value'    => $product->get_id(),
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => array('instock'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_stock_quantity',
            'value'   => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
));
```

The alternative is to check the stock of the returned match(es) in the query loop, but I imagine this to be far less efficient.

Comment: That snippet looks ok. Try to print out the generated SQL with `   echo "Last SQL-Query: {$the_query->request}";` and then run it manually in php admin. Play with the sql until you get the data. Then rewrite the wp query to match that sql.

Comment: Woo have its own queries i would recommend to check this - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to achieve the desired result by passing in two sets of associative arrays into the meta query with an AND relationship, one of which (checking stock) containing a further two nested assoc. arrays with an OR relationship.

Essentially, the meta value has to match either an 'instock' item (if stock control isn't being used), or an item with '> 0' in stock, if it is:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'meta_query' => 
     array(
    'relation' => 'AND',//*
     array(
    'key' => 'new_version', 
            'value' => $product->get_ID(),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
        'relation' => 'OR', //**
        array(
           'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => array('instock'),
                'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
                'key'     => '_stock_quantity',
                'value'   => 0,
                'compare' => '>',
        ),

     ),
    ),
));
```